# Multiple Option values in Scala

Tags: scala

I am parsing three request parameters, all of which are wrapped in an `Option` type. If any of these Options are `None`, then I want to return a 400 error. How do I check if any of these return values are of type `None`?

Comment: what router are you using? Chances are that you can simply make the three parameters mandatory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not just like this?

```
if (o1.isEmpty || o2.isEmpty || o3.isEmpty) BadRequest("Foo")
```

Alternativeley depending on your implementation you might have your options in some kind of collection. Then you could use `exists`

```
if (parsedRequestParameters.exists(_.isEmpty)) BadRequest("Foo")
```

A third alternative you might like, in case you want to do something with the contents of your options:

```
val response = for {
  v1 <- o1
  v2 <- o2
  v3 <- o3
} yield <some response depending on the values of o1..o3>

response getOrElse BadRequest("something wasn't specified")
```

Comment: if any of `o1`, `o2` or `o3` are `None` then what would be the good way to figure out which one failed? Say I want to send this information in `BadRequest` response to the client

Answer (score 20):

Another possibility, added for completeness:

```
(o1, o2, o3) match {
  case(Some(p1), Some(p2), Some(p3)) => Ok // Do stuff with p1, p2, p3
  case _ => BadRequest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to work with them as with a collection of Option[T]

```
scala> Seq(Option(1), Option(5), None)
res0: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(5), None)

scala> val result = res0.exists(_.isEmpty)
result: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness on `exists` over a collection of `Option`, consider also `forall`, as follows,

```
val a = Array(Some(3), None, Some(7))

a.forall(_.nonEmpty)
res: false

a.forall(!_.isEmpty)
res: false

a.forall(_.isDefined)
res: false
```

and

```
val b = Array(Some(3), Some(5), Some(7))    

b.forall(_.nonEmpty)
res: true

b.forall(_.isDefined)
res: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use zip, but it will wrap underlying elements into Seq of nested Pairs that are not easy to flatten for reuse

```
Some(1) zip Some(2) == List((1,2))
Some(2) zip Some(2) zip Some(3) == List(((1,2),3))
Some(1) zip Some(2) zip None == List()
```

or you could do something like this

```
val options = Seq(Some(p1), Some(p2), Some(p3),None)
val parameters = options.flatten
if(parameters.length == options.length) do something with parameters
```